Transfer Function of CDR

Hello, I am trying to write out the transfer function of dual vco locking for PLL-Based CDR.
I came across the problem that I knew how to write the lower part of transfer function.
How do I get the transfer function between LF2 and VCO2.
Thanks a lot
Reference: Deog-Kyoon Jeong, Topics in IC Design: Introduction to Clock and Data Recovery P17

What are these blocks are they multiplicative?

Another architecture of CDR
